# Executing ssh command in a bash shell script within a loop

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to execute an ssh command within a a bash shell script that should perform the following:
1) ssh to host
2) execute command
3) print value of command
4) repeat steps 1 -3
5) exit bash shell script

I have set up password less entry to the remote host, added host key to remote host

I want to test the various states of the httpd process running on the remote host
Within a text file, httpd_process.txt, I have:

/etc/init.d/httpd status (stop, start, restart)

I do the following in the script:

```
while read LINE
do
    echo "Httpd Request: $LINE"
    status=`$LINE`
    echo "Status: $status"
    sleep 5 # sleep so that next 
done < /path_name/httpd_process.txt

exit 0
```

I assumed that each time through the loop another input string is read from the input text file and the request is made to the remote host.
However, what I experience is that after the first request the script terminates. 
Am I correct to assume that as the first request is sent it creates a child process and once that process completes my script completes and the next turn through the loop is not executed?

Answer (score 12):

`ssh` is consuming stdin. Pass it `-n` to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great.      I read about the different flags ssh command uses but I thought the -n flag is only used when running the ssh command in the background, and looking at my script, I did not specifically run the command in the background?

Comment: It *must* be used when `ssh` is run in the background. It *can* be used when `ssh` is running in the foreground.