# Synchronized ssh in the background

Tags: bash, ssh

This is a follow-up to the following question:
[Executing ssh command in a bash shell script within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351022/executing-ssh-command-in-a-bash-shell-script-within-a-loop)

I am doing a similar job:

```
while read line
do
   ssh -n root@$line 'command'
   do something
done
```

The problem is that I want to execute the "do something" part only when the execution of 'command' is complete in the previous ssh line ie I want to wait till the background ssh completes.
I can use sleep, but this does not suit my application. Please guide me.

I don't want to particularly run ssh in the background. I am only doing this so that my loop runs properly. As given in [Executing ssh command in a bash shell script within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351022/executing-ssh-command-in-a-bash-shell-script-within-a-loop)
if we dont give -n flag, the loop terminates after first ssh command execution.

Comment: The problem is solved. A little bit of googling help me:

while read line
do
   ssh root@$line 'command' < /dev/null
   do something
done

In this way, there is no need of -n flag. For more details: http://72.14.189.113/howto/shell/while-ssh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of googling help me:

```
while read line
do
   ssh root@$line 'command' < /dev/null
   do something
done
```

In this way, there is no need of -n flag.
For more details:
http://72.14.189.113/howto/shell/while-ssh/

Comment: There should be no problem with the `-n` flag - it still runs in the foreground with it, unlike the `-f` flag.

Answer (score 2):

If your command is not run in the background, executing `ssh server command` will wait for that command to finish. For example, try this:

```
ssh server "sleep 3"
echo finished
```

This will print "finished" after `sleep 3` actually executed on the remote server (i.e. after 3 seconds).

Try this - make three files in ~/tmp - called lines, parent.sh and child.sh. For a test, make them on some machine that has sshd running, so you can use `ssh localhost` instead of `ssh server`. Put this in them:

- lines

  ```
  line1
  line2
  line3
  ```
- parent.sh

  ```
  while read l; do
    echo next line
    ssh -n localhost "~/tmp/child.sh $l"
  done < lines
  echo parent
  ```
- child.sh

  ```
  echo child processing: $1
  sleep 2
  echo child done
  ```

When you run parent:

```
$ cd ~/tmp
$ ./parent.sh
```

the output will be this:

```
next line
child processing: line1
child done
next line
child processing: line2
child done
next line
child processing: line3
child done
parent
```

which shows that child will execute before the parent will continue processing a next line. You will see a 2 second sleep (a result of `sleep 2` executing in the child.sh) between "child processing" and "child done" lines.

Note that `ssh -n` is not for running `ssh` in the background - it's for not consuming stdin. To run ssh in background, `ssh -f` can be used - see `man ssh`.

Comment: I have edited the question and added why I am executing ssh in the background. I want to somehow either find a way so that loop runs without ssh being run in the background, or some way to detect completion of this ssh process.

Comment: See my edit - please try what I put there to see if that works as you expect.

Comment: You are right - -n helps to consume stdin. I have used /dev/null to read input from, and code runs fine without -n.